# Prove $(A \lor B \rightarrow C) \wedge (C \rightarrow D \wedge C) \wedge (C \rightarrow D) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow D)$ by rules of inference $\:\:$

Tags: logic, solution-verification

## Task: Prove following with rules of inference (do not use truth table)

$$
(A \vee B \rightarrow C) \wedge (C \rightarrow D \wedge C) \wedge (C \rightarrow D) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow D)
$$

## Attempt to prove

1. $A \vee B \rightarrow C$ (premise)
2. $C \rightarrow D \wedge C$ (premise)
3. $C \rightarrow D$ (premise)
4. $A \vee B \rightarrow D \wedge C$ (Hypothetical syllogism 1,2)
5. $\neg(A \vee B) \vee (D \wedge C)$ (Logical equivalence 4)
6. $(\neg A \wedge \neg B)\vee (D \wedge C)$ (Logical equivalence 5)
7. $\neg A \vee D$ (Add 6)
8. $A \rightarrow D$ (Logical equivalence)

Q.E.D.

---

Is my proof valid?

Comment: Either the formula or the proof are incorrect, you have an $\lor$ followed by an $\land$, but you interpreted them all as premises.

Comment: @LukeCollins There would be typo in the formula, I'll fix that

Comment: What do you get when you evaluate the formula with A being true and all the rest being false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how technical you want to be, but you actually gave the proof for $$A\lor B\to C, C\to D\land C, C\to D \vdash A\to D,$$ not what you showed. You would have to use $\land$-elimination to obtain what you dubbed the "premises" separately. This is the difference between a "proof" (in a metalanguage) and a "true implication".

Have you encountered the symbol $\vdash$ before? If not, don't worry about my point. As long as you only applied the rules you are allowed to apply, then the actual reasoning behind the proof you provided appears to be correct.

(Usually, I take the deduction rules listed [here](https://drmenguin.com/assets/files/logic_proof_reddit.pdf) for propositional logic).

Comment: I haven't encountered this symbol before. I'm taking a course called "Algorithm mathematics" which introduces us to various topics including introduction to logic.

Comment: Yes, probably these subtle distinctions are not that important then. Do you have a list of rules which you are allowed to apply to prove a formula? And if so, is each step you carried out justified by one of these rules? If yes, then your proof is correct.

Comment: Yes we do indeed.It's in Finnish but you can probably understand it, here is the list https://i.imgur.com/qVTimfL.png

Comment: I'm not quite sure if my interpretation of "Add rule" is correct on 7. row

Comment: Ah okay. The symbol $A\vdash B$ is basically like an inline version of $\frac AB$, so you actually do have to make some changes. You do not have three premises, but one (the whole thing before the $\to$). You need to first separate the conjoined statements using the _Simp_ rule.

Comment: Your use of the _Add_ rule is also incorrect. You need to first expand the brackets with _Osittelu_, and then you can use _Simp_ to conclude $\neg A \lor D$.